# GHCI Prettty Printer - is not rendered with a color that would make it noticeable

Tags: haskell, ghci

For example typing -1 in console renders as 1:

[image]

When the text is selected then it is seen that it is actually -1:

[image]

.ghci file:

```
import qualified IPPrint
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Colourise as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Output as HsColour

let myColourPrefs = HsColour.defaultColourPrefs { HsColour.conid = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow, HsColour.Bold], HsColour.conop = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow], HsColour.string = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Green], HsColour.char = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Cyan], HsColour.number = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Red, HsColour.Bold], HsColour.layout = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White], HsColour.keyglyph = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White] }

let myPrint :: (Show a) => a -> IO (); myPrint = putStrLn . HsColour.hscolour (HsColour.TTYg HsColour.XTerm256Compatible) myColourPrefs False False "" False . IPPrint.pshow
:set -interactive-print=myPrint

:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXλ> \ESC[m\STX"
:set prompt-cont "   | "
:set +m
```

**Update**

Following http://teh.id.au/posts/2017/02/13/interactive-print/index.html the results are a bit better but still could be improved:

```
import Text.Show.Pretty (ppShow)
import Language.Haskell.HsColour
import Language.Haskell.HsColour.Colourise
let colorPrint = putStrLn . hscolour TTY defaultColourPrefs False False "" False . ppShow
:set -interactive-print=colorPrint
```

**Update**

The issue is that the dash prefixing negative numbers is misclassified as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Because there wasn't an easy way to submit a patch to the actual issue I set the comment color to be same as the digits so that it is readable:

```
HsColour.comment  = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Red, HsColour.Bold]
```

.ghci

```
:load ~/.ghci.hs
:set -interactive-print=myPrint

:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXλ> \ESC[m\STX"
:set prompt-cont "   | "
:set +m
```

.ghci.hs

```
import qualified IPPrint
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Colourise as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Output as HsColour

myColourPrefs = HsColour.defaultColourPrefs
    { HsColour.conid    = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow, HsColour.Bold]
    , HsColour.conop    = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow]
    , HsColour.string   = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Green]
    , HsColour.char     = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Cyan]
    , HsColour.number   = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Red, HsColour.Bold]
    , HsColour.layout   = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White]
    , HsColour.keyglyph = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White]
    , HsColour.comment  = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Red, HsColour.Bold] }

myPrint :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
myPrint = putStrLn . HsColour.hscolour (HsColour.TTYg HsColour.XTerm256Compatible) myColourPrefs False False "" False . IPPrint.pshow
```